# Mathematical logic question propsitional logic

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

"When the front and back door are closed then the light is off"

p - "front"
q - "light is off"
r - "back doors are closed"

$$(p\land r) \rightarrow q$$

Would this be logically correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, not quite: you need to say more about what $p$ denotes.

The one change you need to make is  denoting, by $\;p,\,$ "the front **door is closed.**" I'm assuming this is what you meant $p$ to represent.

Then together with $r:$ "the back door is closed", and $q$ "the light is off", your translation is then correct: $$(p\land r) \rightarrow q$$

Comment: @amWhy: Clean write - up +1